# Why is my CheckedListBoxEdit not binding to a list of items?

Tags: data-binding, devexpress

In the following code:

```
container.checkedComboServicePoints.Properties.DataSource = allPharmacyServicePoints;
container.checkedComboServicePoints.Properties.ValueMember = "UnitOrCellId";
container.checkedComboServicePoints.Properties.DisplayMember = "Name";
container.checkedComboServicePoints.Properties.EditValueType = EditValueTypeCollection.List;

container.checkedListServicePoints.DataSource = allPharmacyServicePoints;
container.checkedListServicePoints.ValueMember = "UnitOrCellId";
container.checkedListServicePoints.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

`checkedComboServicePoints` is a `CheckedComboBoxEdit` and `checkedListServicePoints` is a `CheckedListBoxEdit`. The `CheckedComboBoxEdit` binds fine and I can see my bound items in the dropdown, but my `checkedListServicePoints` always comes up a blank square at runtime. I do believe I satisfied all the requirements in the DexExpress forum answer I found [here](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T464731/checkedlistboxcontrol-how-to-bind-it-to-a-data-source), so why isn't my `CheckedListBoxEdit` binding?

I have both binding targets in my code because one works and the second one that doesn't work would be a great replacement for the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
container.checkedListServicePoints.DataSource = allPharmacyServicePoints.ToList;
container.checkedListServicePoints.ValueMember = "UnitOrCellId";
container.checkedListServicePoints.DisplayMember = "Name";
container.checkedListServicePoints.SelectedValue = "UnitOrCellId";
```